# Correct way of using janet_wrap_array

Tags: c, c-api, janet

I am trying to use janet c api on ncurses and I am not getting what I expected.

I tried to define the function as such on the c file

```c
static Janet jgetyx(int32_t argc, Janet *argv){
  janet_fixarity(argc, 1);
  WINDOW *win = (WINDOW *) janet_getpointer(argv, 0);
  int y, x; 
  getyx(win, y, x);
  int *yxpos[2] = {y, x};
  return janet_wrap_array((JanetArray *) &yxpos);
}
```

And I called the defined function like so

```
(nc/mvwprintw win 2 2 (string (get info 1) " " (get info 0)))
```

But my result was

```
          this is the header─┐
          │this is a box     │
          │ 4.64148e-310 3.458
          46e-323            │
          │                  │
          │                  │
          │                  │
          │                  │
          │                  │
          └──────────────────┘
```

I expected to have the values on the second line of the box, but instead I got the memory address for what it seems... My rusty knowledge of c cannot bring me any closer to the solution...

Could anyone help me?

The code can be found [here](https://git.sr.ht/%7Elucasemmoreira/janet-ncurses/tree/feature/win-info) on `test/term-info.janet`.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I also asked on the [repository](https://github.com/janet-lang/janet/issues/805) issues. A way that works is:

```c
int y, x;
getyx(win, y, x);
JanetArray *arr = janet_array(2);
janet_array_push(arr, janet_wrap_integer(y));
janet_array_push(arr, janet_wrap_integer(x));
return janet_wrap_array(arr);
```